# xml parsing Python reads file incorrectly

Tags: python, xml

I am currently trying to parse an xml file online and obtain the data I need from this file. My code is displayed below:

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import pandas as pd
import time

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mesowest/getobextXml.php?sid=KBFI&num=360')
page_content = page.read()
with open('KBFI.xml', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(page_content)

data = []

xml = parse('KBFI.xml')
percp = 0
for station in xml.getElementsByTagName('station'):
for ob in xml.getElementsByTagName('ob'):
    # Convert time sting to time_struct ignoring last 4 chars ' PDT'
    ob_time = time.strptime(ob.getAttribute('time')[:-4],'%d %b %I:%M %p')
    for variable in xml.getElementsByTagName('variable'):
        if variable.getAttribute('var') == 'PCP1H':
            percp = True
            # UnIndent if you want all variables
            if variable.getAttribute('value') == 'T':
                data.append([ob_time.tm_mday,
                             ob_time.tm_hour,
                             ob_time.tm_min,
                             0])
            elif variable.getAttribute('value') >= 0:
                data.append((ob_time.tm_mday,
                            ob_time.tm_hour,
                            ob_time.tm_min,
                            variable.getAttribute('value')))
    if not percp:
        # If PCP1H wasn't found add as 0
        data.append([ob_time.tm_mday,
                    ob_time.tm_hour,
                    ob_time.tm_min,
                    0])
print data
```

Unfortunately I cannot post an image of the xml file, but a version of it will be saved into your current directory if my script is run.

I would like the code to simply check for the existence of the 'variable' PCPH1 and print the 'value' if it exists (only one entry per 'ob'). If it doesn't exist or provides a value of 'T', I would like it to print '0' for that particular hour. Currently the output (the script I provided can be run to see the output) contains completely incorrect values and there are six entries per hour instead of one. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue in your code , in each `for` loop, you are getting the elements using -

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('ob')
```

This actually starts the search from the `xml` element, which in your case in the root element, same in case of `xml.getElementsByTagName('variable')` , this starts the search at the root element, so each time you are getting all the elements with tag `variable` , this is why you are getting 6 entries per hour, instead of one (since there are 6 of them in the complete xml).

You should instead get using -

```
ob.getElementsByTagName('variable')
```

And the ob element using -

```
station.getElementsByTagName('ob')
```

So that we only check inside the particular element we are currently iterating over (not the complete xml document).

Also, another side issue , you are doing -

```
elif variable.getAttribute('value') >= 0:
```

If I am not wrong, `getAttribute()` returns string, so this check would always be true, irrespective of what the actual `value` is. In the xml, I see that `value` has strings as well as numbers, so not really sure what you want that condition to be (Though this is not the main issue, the main issue is the one I described above).

Example code changes -

```
import urllib2
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import pandas as pd
import time

page = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mesowest/getobextXml.php?

sid=KBFI&num=360')
page_content = page.read()
with open('KBFI.xml', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(page_content.decode())

data = []

xml = parse('KBFI.xml')
percp = 0
for station in xml.getElementsByTagName('station'):
    for ob in station.getElementsByTagName('ob'):
        # Convert time sting to time_struct ignoring last 4 chars ' PDT'
        ob_time = time.strptime(ob.getAttribute('time')[:-4],'%d %b %I:%M %p')
        for variable in ob.getElementsByTagName('variable'):
            if variable.getAttribute('var') == 'PCP1H':
                percp = True
                # UnIndent if you want all variables
                if variable.getAttribute('value') == 'T':
                    data.append([ob_time.tm_mday,
                                 ob_time.tm_hour,
                                 ob_time.tm_min,
                                 0])
                elif variable.getAttribute('value') >= 0:
                    data.append((ob_time.tm_mday,
                                ob_time.tm_hour,
                                ob_time.tm_min,
                                variable.getAttribute('value')))
        if not percp:
            # If PCP1H wasn't found add as 0
            data.append([ob_time.tm_mday,
                        ob_time.tm_hour,
                        ob_time.tm_min,
                        0])
print data
```

Comment: That's awesome! That helped a lot. Thank you. But now, the code works perfectly until it reaches an entry where PCP1H occurs and is >0. After the entries with PCP1H are recorded, the program stops. Do you know why it does not continue after this point?

Comment: Did you take note of the **Also, another side issue , you are doing -** I desccribed in my answer ?

Comment: Yes. And it does work correctly (it displays '0' when PCP1H='T' and the correct number when PCP1H has an actual value). So can the cause of the program ending prematurely be .getAttribute()?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the value of variable would always be either `T` or a number? And is that the complete code for which your program is prematurely ending?

Comment: Yes to both. The program displays 'T' when there is less than 1/100 of an inch of precipitation.. and the variable will not appear at all if there is no trace of precipitation

Comment: Try changing the condition to - `float(variable.getAttribute('value')) >= 0`

Comment: That did not work. I'm so sorry I'm causing so much trouble!

Comment: Its fine, what exactly are you seeing when you say prematurely ended (and what did you expect to see?)

Comment: The output is correct up to a point, but the program exits my loop after it reads PCPH1 with values. Once PCPH1 disappears again, the program doesn't read any more data points. No error is given. It should continue for another ~200 points

Comment: that is the code you have written right? I do not see you checking for anything other than PCPH1 .

Comment: Yes, I'm only checking for PCPH1. I just don't know why the program is providing ~50 data points instead of reading all 360 that I have in the xml file

Comment: Ok finally I get the issue, you should have started with that :D . set `percp = False` before - `ob_time = time.strptime(ob.getAttribute('time')[:-4],'%d %b %I:%M %p')` and try.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!! Words are hard.. haha I was having a hard time articulating what I was trying to say!! Thanks for saving me hours of work today!